# What happens when you touch two buttons at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

If my `UIView` has two buttons, what happens if I touch both the button at same time?

- Will both the selectors be performed
- No selector is performed
- or something else happens

Based on the answer, it looks like both the selectors will be performed.

So I think when we don't need multi touch in a view we can disable it to overcome both the selectors being performed at the same time.

Is there a solution to support multi touch and handle multi selectors being performed?

Comment: Why don't you build a simple view and find out for yourself? :)

Comment: Looking for answers that can provide some in-depth reasons as to why :) If I just do it myself I know what will happen but I need to know the reason behind it.

Comment: on a multitouch screen (the iPhone has such screen since 2007) all events are performed independently from each other... have you not tried to test it, maybe?

Comment: @Vig explain a bit better your question so I can update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both selectors will be performed.
This is interesting if you're building a quiz app with multiple answers (my case).
If you don't want this behaviour, there are ways to control the touches of the view.

Comment: Could you tell how I can control them. I have an app with two answers. When i click both app & animation go crazy

Comment: @GabyFitcal naturally UI elements don't hold any relationship among them. Then if you tap on two buttons at the same time they will both (in fact any number) perform its actions.
The only way would be to add logic behind so only 1 button can perform an action at a time. This would also be doable using reactive programming if you don't want to add too much logic into it.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: And how I can add the logic behind?